# How to use ScrolLeft and ScrollRight Methods of QML Charts

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtcharts

I need to scroll a QT Graph using a `scrollbar` and for that, i have created my own custom `scrollbar` using `Rectangle` and `MouseArea` which can be dragged.

When i tried to scroll a Chart using `ScrollRight` and `ScrollLeft` Methods i am not able to link/bind the `ScrollBar` `X` with the `ChartView` content X.Following is the code :

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtCharts 2.0

Window {
    id: window
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    ChartView {
        id: chartview
        width: parent.width
        height: 300

        LineSeries {
            name: "LineSeries"
            axisX: ValueAxis {
                min: 0
                max: 100
                tickCount: 12
                labelFormat: "%.0f"
            }

            axisY: ValueAxis {
                min: 0
                max: 70
                tickCount: 5
                labelFormat: "%.0f"
            }
            XYPoint { x: 0; y: 0.0 }
            XYPoint { x: 1.1; y: 3.2 }
            XYPoint { x: 1.9; y: 2.4 }
            XYPoint { x: 2.1; y: 2.1 }
            XYPoint { x: 2.9; y: 2.6 }
            XYPoint { x: 3.4; y: 2.3 }
            XYPoint { x: 200.1; y: 3.1 }
        }
    }

    /* Rectangle base for horizontal scroll bar */
    Rectangle{
        id:rectHorScrollBase
        width:parent.width
        height:parent.height * 0.10
        anchors.top:chartview.bottom
        anchors.topMargin: (parent.height * 0.01)
        color:"transparent"
        visible: true

        /* Rectangle indicating scroll path*/
        Rectangle {
            id:rectHorScrollPath
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height
            anchors.left:parent.left

            radius: 2
            color: "lightblue"
        }

        /* Actual scroll rectaangle which will be dragged */
        Rectangle {
            id: rectHorScroll
            property var prevX : 0

            anchors.top : parent.top
            width: 50
            height: parent.height
            color: "green"

            /* Mouser area to drag the rectangle and to move Chart */
            MouseArea {
                id:mouseAreaHorScroll

                anchors.fill: parent
                drag.target: parent
                drag.minimumX: 0
                drag.maximumX: chartview.width - width
                drag.axis: Drag.XAxis

                onReleased: {
                    console.log("x in Released ===",rectHorScroll.x)
                    rectHorScroll.prevX = rectHorScroll.x
                }
            }

            onXChanged: {

                // HOW TO HANDLE THE SCROLL BASED ON x ? 
                if(mouseAreaHorScroll.drag.active)
                {
                    if(x > prevX)
                    {
                        chartview.scrollRight(x) // NOT WORKING
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        chartview.scrollLeft(x) //NOT WORKING
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

1) How to map `scrollBar X` with `ChartView` Content `X` ?

2) The `scrollbar` should not go beyond maximum and minimum Value of X Axis. How to do that?

3) There should be a sync between `ScrollBar` and `ChartView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it works as expected. Let us analyze what you are doing:

```
onXChanged: {

    // HOW TO HANDLE THE SCROLL BASED ON x ?
    if(mouseAreaHorScroll.drag.active)
    {
        if(x > prevX)
        {
            chartview.scrollRight(x) // NOT WORKING
        }
        else
        {
            chartview.scrollLeft(x) //NOT WORKING
        }
    }
}
```

First of all, you `scrollRight` when `x` is larger than `prevX` - which works perfectly. However you `scrollRight` for `x` pixels - which grows with the movement, so the movement is not linear to the movement of the scroll bar.

The `scrollLeft` is indeed (almost) never invoked, which is obvious: you don't update `prevX` so only when `x === 0 ( = prevX)` you `scrollLeft(0)` - which doesn't move.

The first change we need to apply, is to update `prevX` at the end of the handler.
The second change is, that we only want to move as far as we moved the handle since the last run of the code.

The solution therefore looks like this:

```
onXChanged: {

    // HOW TO HANDLE THE SCROLL BASED ON x ?
    if(mouseAreaHorScroll.drag.active)
    {
        if(x > prevX)
        {
            chartview.scrollRight(x - prevX) // Only move the difference
        }
        else
        {
            chartview.scrollLeft(prevX - x) //Only move the difference
        }
        prevX = x // Update prevX
    }
}
```

Instead of handling that stuff manually, and calling those functions, you can also just *map the visible part of the axis to x* - remove your handles for this and change axisX accordingly:

```
axisX: ValueAxis {
    min: rectHorScroll.x / (rectHorScrollBase.width - rectHorScroll.width) * 100
    max: rectHorScroll.x / (rectHorScrollBase.width - rectHorScroll.width) * 100 + 100
    tickCount: 12
    labelFormat: "%.0f"
}
```

Here you need to find the right way to apply the mapping, that you get the right range.

Then you can also use regular components, like a `Slider` to simulate the scrollbar:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtCharts 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    ChartView {
        id: chartview
        width: parent.width
        height: 300

        LineSeries {
            name: "LineSeries"
            axisX: ValueAxis {
                property real minValue: 0
                property real maxValue: 200
                property real range: 100
                min: minValue + sb.position * (maxValue - minValue - range)
                max: minValue + sb.position * (maxValue - minValue - range) + range
                tickCount: 12
                labelFormat: "%.0f"
            }

            axisY: ValueAxis {
                min: 0
                max: 70
                tickCount: 5
                labelFormat: "%.0f"
            }
            XYPoint { x: 0; y: 0.0 }
            XYPoint { x: 1.1; y: 3.2 }
            XYPoint { x: 1.9; y: 2.4 }
            XYPoint { x: 2.1; y: 2.1 }
            XYPoint { x: 2.9; y: 2.6 }
            XYPoint { x: 3.4; y: 2.3 }
            XYPoint { x: 200.1; y: 3.1 }
        }


    }

    Slider {
        id: sb
        anchors {
            bottom: parent.bottom
            left: parent.left
            right: parent.right
        }
        height: 30
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @derM both the solution works perfectly. Can you please suggest how to move the graph if data is generated realtime ?. I have updated my question please check.

Comment: Uhm... I need to look into that chart stuff later. I have not used that yet. You would need to find the min and max x as the chart evolves... Maybe you can ask a new question for it. I don't know now, but I feel your update goes beyond the scope of one question and might be relevant separately to others. ofc. maybe it is really simple.

Comment: Ok. I will post it as a new question. Thanks for the solutions it gave me new ideas to implement for real time.